# simple approach to create a template file to be changed as needed

Tags: python, templates

I have been trying to get into python programming for a bit but cannot find the right moment or project. Now I may have! I am trying to generate multiple files that are used as input for a DFT (density functional theory) software (quantum espresso) and I would like to use python for this.

An input file looks like this:

```
&control
 calculation         = 'scf'
 restart_mode        = 'from_scratch'
 prefix              = 'pto'
 disk_io             = 'low'
 tstress             = .true.
 tprnfor             = .true.
 etot_conv_thr       = 1.e-6
 forc_conv_thr       = 1.e-5
 verbosity           = 'high'
 pseudo_dir          = '../pp/'
 outdir              = 'pto'
/

&system
 ibrav               = 6
 celldm(1)           = 7.37934
 celldm(3)           = 1.06428
 nat                 = 5
 ntyp                = 3
 ecutwfc             = 75.
/

&electrons
 diagonalization     = 'ppcg'
 mixing_beta         = 0.1
 mixing_mode         = 'plain'
 conv_thr            = 1.e-10
/

ATOMIC_SPECIES
 Pb  207.2   Pb.upf
 Ti   47.867 Ti.upf
 O    15.999  O.upf

ATOMIC_POSITIONS {crystal}
Pb  0.0    0.0    z1
O   0.5    0.5    z2 
Ti  0.5    0.5    z3
O   0.0    0.5    z4
O   0.5    0.0    z5

K_POINTS {automatic}
3 3 3
```

What I would like to change is the `z1, z2, z3, z4 and z5` parts in the atomic positions section. My idea was to create a file like this to be used as a template, use it as input for the python script, search for z1 (and also the rest of the zX) and replace it with the value I need. Save to a new file and repeat as needed.

The trouble is, I don't know how to approach this. I know how to generate the zZ values and that's about it.

Is there a simple way to approach this?

Thank you!

Comment: How might the modified parts look once changed please?

Comment: sorry i should have mentioned, they are just numbers like the two other columns in that section. These are atomic coordinates so the first column is the atomic symbol, the second column is the x coordinate, the third is the y coordinate and the fourth, the one with the zX is the z coordinate.